# removeChild - remove first or last node

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery one-liner which I'm trying to convert to vanilla JavaScript.

```
$('#nav ul li:' + (dir == -1 ? 'last' : 'first')).remove();
```

This works. But do I need 5 lines to replace a single line of jQuery ?

```
var li = document.querySelectorAll('#nav ul li');
var first = li[0];
var last = li[li.length- 1];
theParent = document.querySelector("#nav ul");
theParent.removeChild(dir == -1 ? last : first);
```

Comment: You could wrap those lines in a function and then it would be one line, but what would you gain?

Comment: can't you just use `document.querySelector('#nav ul li:' + (dir == -1 ? 'last' : 'first')).remove()`?

Comment: jQuery helps for a reason. That's essentially what jQuery is doing behind the scenes. Also @Steve `.remove()` does not work in IE.

Comment: @Steve : We can't include :first and :last in querySelector.
SyntaxError: '#nav ul li:first' is not a valid selector

Comment: Thanks for the info; it does look like jQuery made a custom implementation for a reason. You might be able to use `:first-child` and `:last-child`, depending on your structure.

Comment: Here is the jQuery implementation of [`remove()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/662083ed7bfea6bad5f9cd4060dab77c1f32aacd/src/manipulation.js#L216-L235). (`element` is the element called upon and `selector` is an optional selector as described in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/remove/), `keepData` is not relevant for this question since [it's not passed as argument](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/662083ed7bfea6bad5f9cd4060dab77c1f32aacd/src/manipulation.js#L324-L326) by jQuery.)

Comment: Your vanilla doesn't do the same thing as the jQuery code if you have more than one `ul` in `#nav`, because `theParent` (not initialized in your code) will always be the first `<ul>` in `#nav`, while `querySelectorAll('#nav ul li')` selects all `<li>`s in all `<ul>`s in `#nav`. And yes, you need all those 5 or more lines. Main jQuery advantages: extra methods, shorter and more flexible syntax (i.e.: chaining), browser quirk workarounds and auto closures. Switching to vanilla is more than just syntax. You have to do all of the above yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest way to write that in vanilla would be:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("#nav ul li"),
    index = -1 == dir ? nodes.length-1 : 0;
nodes[index].parentElement.removeChild(nodes[index]);
```

...methinks. (obviously, `nodes` and `index` could be renamed to 1 letter var names and spaces could be removed, but that's not the point here).

By the way, as pointed out in the q comment, your version doesn't remove correct `<li>` when there are two or more `<ul>`s in `#nav`

Testing:

```js
// comment/uncomment this to test:
let dir = 1;

var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("#nav ul li"),
    index = -1 == dir ? nodes.length-1 : 0;
nodes[index].parentElement.removeChild(nodes[index]);
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>fourth</li>
    <li>fifth</li>
    <li><ul>
      <li>sixth</li>
      <li>seventh</li>
    </ul></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```